# Is there a way in Javascript to have percentage(%) sign internationalization?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, percentage

Basically I'm trying to see if a predefined way exists for this. I have percentages such as 1.15%, 2%, 6.1%.

For some locales a space must be placed in front of the sign whereas for others this is not a requirement.

E.g.

- For some countries the percentage will look like this: 1.15%
- For others like this: 1.15 %

Even though I found a way to internationalise the number itself (toLocaleString) I'm wondering if something like this exists for the percentage as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat):

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style:'percent'}).format(0.5)
// "50%"
new Intl.NumberFormat('fr', {style:'percent'}).format(0.5)
// "50 %"
new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {style:'percent'}).format(0.5)
// answer depends on your default locale
```

Comment: It should be noted that IE 11 support may or may not be available.

Comment: thank you, very useful. I also added maximumFractionDigits and it works perfectly.